# Jmeter BeanShell Assertion not failing the tests

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests, beanshell

I am learning into Jmeter.

I have a BeanShell Assertion which should make the tests fail (failure is hardcoded into the assertion). But all the tests pass. What am I doing wrong?

My understanding is that if the BSA sets

```
Faliure = true;
```

the assertion fails.
But in my case it does not fail.

Please see:

[image: Assertion]

[image: Result]

You can see the disabled XPath Assertion on the screenshot which is not fulfilled, if I enable that one, that one does fail the test as I expect.

Update: now I see why it didn't fail the tests: Failure has a typo... Then the question: Why did it even run? Isn't this java? Isn't this an undeclared variable?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 typos, correct statements are:

```
Failure = true;
FailureMessage = "Here goes the failure message";
```

Assertion is successful as the code is fine from Beanshell perspective, in Beanshell you don't need to explicitly define object class. As long as it is valid code - your assertion is successful.

Here is a couple of troubleshooting techniques:

1. Adding `debug();` as a first line of your Beanshell script will trigger debugging output to [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29)
2. By surrounding your code in [try/catch block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html) like:

   ```
   try {
       //your code here
   }
   catch (Throwable ex) {
       log.error("Failure", ex);
       throw ex;
   }
   ```

   you will have the relevant stacktrace printed to *jmeter.log* file

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for comprehensive information on using Beanshell test elements in JMeter